# jQuery ajax upload with progress bar - no flash

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, upload

I am looking for a file uploader similar to [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) with progress bar that doesn't rely on flash, preferably using jQuery - is this possible?

Comment: It is possible but it is quite tricky get working, jQuery won't be enough, you will need to do some server side coding as well. Have a look at this, assuming you're using PHP: http://nixboxdesigns.com/demos/jquery-uploadprogress.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. A couple sites with different code and tutorials are:

- http://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress (ninja'd by DrJokepu ;)
- [http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120414125425/http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar)

Comment: The t.wits.sg blog post references http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress, which is a great solution.

Comment: this link http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/ is broken

Comment: Murali: use Web Archive:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120414125425/http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

Hello try my beta ajax mutiple upload jquery based, simple efficient download it at: http://www.albanx.com/  . no flash, with progress, work over https, support main browsers..
EDIT:
find final project here http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it can cross all browser. IE6-9 can't support the real upload progress bar if no flash. Cause js can't get the file size without File Read API.

Comment: PHP can get the upload file size and return it to JS via AJAX. As a matter of fact, PHP can get all info about the file and return it via AJAX as a JSON string, and it would work in any browser that supports AJAX (including IE6). You don't need Flash. You do, however, still need to find a way to report the upload progress, which involves JS long polling and monitoring how much of the file is on the server vs. its filesize in PHP.