# Upload an image using jquery AJAX in .net MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery, file-upload

I am creating one application in .net MVC, in which I am using jQuery AJAX to post some data to server. The data posting is working fine, but I also need to upload one image along with the data. I have searched on stack over flow for similar question but they are not able to help me. I donot want to use flash to upload file, pure jquery solution will help me.

Using some solution I tried to post to server, but on server side I am not getting file data.

Please can some body tell me how to implement file upload in jQuery ajax?

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714507/jquery-ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-no-flash) may be useful. But I think your options are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck if you want ajax like uploading without flash. Due to security limitations javascript can't do all the things required. Off the top of my head i'd say your only other option will be to use an iframe to make it appear as thought it was an ajax post.

Why not use flash though? YUI Uploader is amazingly simple and works great!