# upload image with percentage progress bar without using flash

Tags: jquery

I already searched on how to upload image with progress bar but all I can find is with using a flash-based upload. Can someone give me any idea regarding this topic?

Comment: i like the concept of using math.random......

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714507/jquery-ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-no-flash), you will need some form of server side coding.

PHP:

- http://github.com/drogus/jquery-upload-progress
- http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/

ASP.NET MVC

- http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/

Comment: And yet, neither PHP examples are compatible with MVC and the MVC example has flash... Bad form Peter.