# Implement the progress bar with the ajaxupload while uploading videos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I need to show the exact time estimated with the nice progress bar while uploading the video.

I am using the ajaxupload js + php codignator for the server side.

Answer (score 1):

jqUploader is a jquery plugin that substitutes html file input fields with a flash-based file upload widget, allowing to display a progressbar and percentage.

http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/

File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bars and preview images for jQuery.

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

More info: [jQuery ajax upload with progress bar - no flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714507/jquery-ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-no-flash)

Comment: Thanks! for this answer. I have also refereed the same plugin  jQuery-File-Upload but need some solution with ajaxupload.js

Comment: Well it means you need php related help to fetch the progress while the file is being uploaded. This might help. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/

Answer (score 0):

You will have difficulty doing this on a PHP stack, but if back-compatibility isn't an issue you should check out the HTML5 [filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for a possible client-side solution.