# Setting Context Keys in AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been trying to use the ContextKeys of AjaxControlToolkit's AjaxFileUpload control but I have been unsuccessful at setting the value at runtime.  If I set it to a static value in the markup it works but when I try to set it from the code behind or in javascript it fails.  I have looked at a few different examples of fixes but I haven't been able to solve the issue.  Here is one example:

[How can I use the ContextKeys property for the AjaxFileUpload control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080186/how-can-i-use-the-contextkeys-property-for-the-ajaxfileupload-control/13084169#13084169)

The code in the files no longer resembles these to be able to make these edits to the toolkit.

The markup that works by setting it statically is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload  ContextKeys="Testing" ID="ajaxFileUploadAttachments" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="ajaxFileUploadAttachments_UploadComplete"  OnClientUploadStart="uploadStarted" />
</div>
</form>
```

and code behind:

```
    protected void ajaxFileUploadAttachments_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{



    String ContextKeyValue = ajaxFileUploadAttachments.ContextKeys;

    string fileNameWithPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + e.FileName.ToString();
    ajaxFileUploadAttachments.SaveAs(fileNameWithPath);

}
```

In this version, the context key gets passed.  If I try to set it from the code behind in the page load via:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ajaxFileUploadAttachments.ContextKeys = "TestingFromPageLoad";
}
```

It doesn't work and I still get the static value of the control from the markup.

I have tried via an example in javascript using the OnClientUploadStart but still only the static value gets passed.

Anyone have a solution to this issue.  I like the control but I need to be able to pass it a value without using session variables.

Thanks for any help and its greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an FYI.  I the Javascript I was testing is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080240/returning-data-with-ajaxcontroltoolkits-async-ajaxfileupload-control-in-asp-net